# Разбор работы ArrayList при расширении внутреннего массива

Tags: java, коллекции, arraylist

Хотел бы уточнить работу ArrayList(a):
 когда нужно записать во внутренний массив ещё один элемент, а свободного места там нет, то внутри ArrayList(а) делается вот что:

> 1) создаётся ещё один массив, в полтора раза больше размера
>   внутреннего массива, плюс один элемент. То есть (старый_размер * 1.5)
>   + 1?
>
> 2) все элементы из старого массива копируются в новый массив.
>
> 3) новый массив сохраняется во внутренней переменной объекта
>   ArrayList, старый массив объявляется мусором (мы просто перестаём
>   хранить на него ссылку).

Хотел бы уточнить потому что читал документацию и попытался перевести как мог

Comment: Все верно. Хотя, размер массива без +1. Просто 1.5 раза больше

Answer (score 1):

В документации [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) по этому поводу написано следующее:

> ... As elements are added to an ArrayList, its capacity grows automatically. The details of the growth policy are not specified beyond the fact that adding an element has constant amortized time cost.
>
> ... *При добавлении элементов в ArrayList, его емкость увеличивается автоматически. Детали политики роста не определены за исключением того факта, что добавление элемента имеет постоянные амортизированные временные затраты.*

Т.е. разработчики не гарантируют как именно будет изменяться размер массива при добавлении в него элементов. Гарантируется только то, что при большом количестве добавлений средняя скорость будет примерно пропорциональна количеству добавленных элементов.

Чтобы получить более конкретное представление можно читать исходники `ArrayList`. Но при этом надо иметь ввиду, что:

- наследники `ArrayList` могут переопределить поведение;
- политика роста может быть изменена (хоть это и маловероятна) в следующей версии.

Читаем исходники [`ArrayList`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk10/jdk10/jdk/file/72f33dbfcf3b/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java) начиная с метода `add`. Для удобства я разложил цепочку вызовов сверху вниз:

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    modCount++;
    add(e, elementData, size);
    return true;
}

private void add(E e, Object[] elementData, int s) {
    if (s == elementData.length)
        elementData = grow();
    elementData[s] = e;
    size = s + 1;
}

private Object[] grow() {
    return grow(size + 1);
}

private Object[] grow(int minCapacity) {
    return elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData,
                                           newCapacity(minCapacity));
}

/**
* Returns a capacity at least as large as the given minimum capacity.
* Returns the current capacity increased by 50% if that suffices.
* Will not return a capacity greater than MAX_ARRAY_SIZE unless
* the given minimum capacity is greater than MAX_ARRAY_SIZE.
*
* @param minCapacity the desired minimum capacity
* @throws OutOfMemoryError if minCapacity is less than zero
*/
private int newCapacity(int minCapacity) {
    // overflow-conscious code
    int oldCapacity = elementData.length;
    int newCapacity = oldCapacity + (oldCapacity >> 1);
    if (newCapacity - minCapacity <= 0) {
        if (elementData == DEFAULTCAPACITY_EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA)
            return Math.max(DEFAULT_CAPACITY, minCapacity);
        if (minCapacity < 0) // overflow
            throw new OutOfMemoryError();
        return minCapacity;
    }
    return (newCapacity - MAX_ARRAY_SIZE <= 0)
            ? newCapacity
            : hugeCapacity(minCapacity);
}

private static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 10;
private static final int MAX_ARRAY_SIZE = Integer.MAX_VALUE - 8;

private static int hugeCapacity(int minCapacity) {
    if (minCapacity < 0) // overflow
        throw new OutOfMemoryError();
    return (minCapacity > MAX_ARRAY_SIZE)
            ? Integer.MAX_VALUE
            : MAX_ARRAY_SIZE;
}
```

Из прочитанного строим описание:

- при добавлении элементов, если размера внутреннего массива не хватает:

  1. будет рассчитан минимальный размер массива, который нужен для того чтобы вместить все элементы;
  2. если (старый_размер*1,5) меньше минимального, то:

     - если массив был до этого пуст и минимальный размер меньше 10, то новый размер — 10;
     - если массив был до этого пуст, но минимальный размер больше 10, то новый размер — минимальный размер
     - если оказалось, что минимальный размер меньше нуля, то произошло переполнение и выбрасывается `OutOfMemoryError`.
  3. если (старый_размер*1,5) больше или равен минимальному, то:

     - если (старый_размер*1,5) меньше максимальной длины массива, то новый размер — (старый_размер*1,5);
     - если (старый_размер*1,5) превышает максимальную длину массива и минимальный размер переполнился, то выбрасывается `OutOfMemoryError`
     - если и (старый_размер*1,5) и минимальный размер превышают максимальную длину массива, то новый размер — `Integer.MAX_VALUE`
     - если (старый_размер*1,5) превышает максимальную длину массива, а минимальный размер нет, то новый размер — максимальная длина массива.
  4. старый массив копируется в массив нового размера.

Вроде бы ничего не упустил, если что поправьте. Алгоритм работает как для добавления новых элементов по одному (через `add`) так и скопом (`addAll`).

В общих чертах Ваше описание верно по сути это перевод JavaDoc метода `private int newCapacity`, но, как видите, есть некоторые нюансы при обработке краевых случаев:

- маленький массив будет расширен как минимум до 10;
- если в результате получается значение около `Integer.MAX_VALUE` класс попробует учесть ограничения по размеру массива;
- если через `addAll` добавляется больше половины длины массива, то массив расширится насколько нужно, а не в полтора раза.

Как уже сказано в документации эти нюансы могут изменяться в разных версиях JVM. Поэтому заучивать алгоритм роста и всегда держать его в голове несколько непрактично.

В повседневной жизни обычному программисту нужно знать о внутреннем массиве `ArrayList` то, что он есть и что при увеличении списка он расширяется. Соответственно, если известно заранее до какого размера увеличится список, то лучше этот размер задать через конструктор или `ensureCapacity` чтобы не тратить зря время на расширение списка.

Все остальное можно замерить по мере необходимости. Те немногие программисты, которые занимаются низкоуровневой оптимизацией смогут и заглянуть в исходники и замерить каждое расширение массива если понадобится.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Вы мой спаситель :), хотел спросить вы написали: Как уже сказано в документации эти нюансы могут изменяться в разных версиях JVM. То есть допустим для JDK 7 и JDK 9 нюансы могут менять? Никогда просто не слышал о разных версиях JVM не очень понял эти слова

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван все в нашей жизни меняется. Я когда ковырялся в AL (Java 1.6), метод назывался `ensureCapacity()` и немного другая была логика..

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван Пожалуйста! Да, в новой версии JDK. Еще, JVM может выпустить [другой производитель](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_virtual_machines) и изменить логику по каким-то причинам. Впрочем, не думаю что именно логика `ArrayList` будет часто меняться, но для точности нужно это иметь ввиду.

Comment: А еще хотел спросить именно старый * 1.5 или просто старый?

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван Везде старый*1,5. В коде это строка `int newCapacity = oldCapacity + (oldCapacity >> 1);` после этого старый размер (`oldCapacity`) не используется.